# Калькулятор на java

Tags: java, калькулятор

Я написал прогу, которая может вычислять объем и площадь цилиндра и периметр и площадь круга. Вот код:

```
public class Prigramm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double pi = 3.14;
        System.out.println("Чтобы вызвать формулы цилиндра, введите cylinder");
        System.out.println( "Чтобы вызвать формулы круга, введите circle");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String UserRequest = scan.nextLine();

        switch(UserRequest){
            case "cylinder":
                System.out.println("Чтобы вызвать площадь цилиндра введите Scylinder");
                System.out.println("Чтобы вызвать объем цилиндра введите Vcylinder");
                String UserReqCylinder = scan.nextLine();               
                switch(UserReqCylinder){
                    case "Vcylinder":
                        System.out.println("Введите радиус: ");
                        int UserReqCylinderRad = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Введите высоту: ");
                        int UserReqCylinderH = scan.nextInt();
                        double VCyl = pi * UserReqCylinderRad * UserReqCylinderRad * UserReqCylinderH;
                        System.out.println("Объем равен " + VCyl);
                        break;
                    case "Scylinder":
                        System.out.println("Введите радиус: ");
                        int UserReqCylinderRad1 = scan.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Введите высоту: ");
                        int UserReqCylinderH1 = scan.nextInt();
                        double SCyl = pi * 2 * UserReqCylinderRad1 * UserReqCylinderH1;
                        System.out.println("Площадь равна " + SCyl);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("В списке нет Ваших команд");
                }

            case"circle":
                System.out.println("Чтобы вызвать площадь круга введите Scircle");
                System.out.println("Чтобы вызвать периметр круга введите Pcircle");
                String UserReqCircle = scan.nextLine();
                switch(UserReqCircle){
                    case"Pcircle":
                        System.out.println("Введите радиус ");
                        int UserReqCircleRad = scan.nextInt();
                        double PCir = 2*pi*UserReqCircleRad;
                        System.out.println("Длина окружности равна " + PCir);
                        break;
                    case "Scircle":
                        System.out.println("Введите радиус");
                        int UserReqCircleRad1 = scan.nextInt();
                        double SCir = pi * UserReqCircleRad1 * UserReqCircleRad1;
                        System.out.println("Площадь круга равна " + SCir);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("В списке нет Ваших команд");
                }

        }


        }
    }
```

Когда я ввожу, cylinder, а потом Vcylinder или Scylinder, выводится следующее:

cylinder
Чтобы вызвать площадь цилиндра введите Scylinder

Чтобы вызвать объем цилиндра введите Vcylinder

Vcylinder

Введите радиус:

(ввел радиус)

Введите высоту:

(ввел высоту)

Объем равен (объем)

(и тут самое интересное. Цикл switch на этом должен был остановиться, но почему то, сразу после ответа, выводится следующее:)

Чтобы вызвать площадь круга введите Scircle

Чтобы вызвать периметр круга введите Pcircle

В списке нет Ваших команд

(и программа завершается)

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После `case "cylinder":` у вас не стоит `break`

```
  case "cylinder":
    System.out.println("Чтобы вызвать площадь цилиндра введите Scylinder");
    System.out.println("Чтобы вызвать объем цилиндра введите Vcylinder");
    String UserReqCylinder = scan.nextLine();               
    switch(UserReqCylinder){
        case "Vcylinder":
            System.out.println("Введите радиус: ");
            int UserReqCylinderRad = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите высоту: ");
            int UserReqCylinderH = scan.nextInt();
            double VCyl = pi * UserReqCylinderRad * UserReqCylinderRad * UserReqCylinderH;
            System.out.println("Объем равен " + VCyl);
            break;
        case "Scylinder":
            System.out.println("Введите радиус: ");
            int UserReqCylinderRad1 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите высоту: ");
            int UserReqCylinderH1 = scan.nextInt();
            double SCyl = pi * 2 * UserReqCylinderRad1 * UserReqCylinderH1;
            System.out.println("Площадь равна " + SCyl);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("В списке нет Ваших команд");
    }

  break;
```

Comment: Там break ставить нельзя, иначе следующий оператор switch не будет видеть переменную UserReqCylinder.

Comment: @МиронФисенко, вы не правы. Посмотрите где именно вы пропустили break

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь дошло

Comment: @МиронФисенко, пж-та) После default тоже лучше break поставить - а то потом случится чего и замучаетесь искать